# How to call a variable from nested function in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I wanted to get the value of chkArray variable when called outside the method.

When I called **getValues().total** from outside the method I am getting a error message as cannot read property total of undefined.

```
function getValues(){
chkArray = new Array() ;
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function fire() {
 var total = chkArray.push($(this).val());
console.log(chkArray)    
});
};
```

Kindly, help how to call that variable outside the method

Comment: Im confused as to where `.total` comes in.. `total` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: I have edited please check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getValues() {
  var total = new Array();
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    total.push($(this).val());
  });
  return total;
};

function doSomething() {
  var k = getValues();
  console.log(k);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="1" />
<br />2
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="2" />
<br />3
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="3" />
<br />4
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="4" />
<br />5
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="5" />
<br />
<input type="button" onClick="doSomething()" value="Click me" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your example. I am able to print ["1", "2", "3"] in console.log(total). but after checking the text boxes when I write the code  var k = getValues(); and print console.log(k), I am getting an empty array ([]) I need the values in k after checking in the text boxes

Comment: I have just updated my answer. Just make sure you have selected checkboxes - the only scenario I can imagine where you'll get an empty array is when no checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
  function getValues(){
     var total = new Array() ;
     $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function fire() {
       total.push($(this).val());
      });
   return total;
  };
```

Call function

```
var total= getValues();
console.log(total);
```

Comment: I am getting an empty array. I wanted to get the value of total that is present inside the fire()

Comment: You're getting empty array because you checked no checkboxes, didn't you? And what does `fire()` do? `.each(function () {` would do the same job.

Comment: @StanimirStoyanov I gave console.log(total) inside the fire() it returning array with elements but the returned total gives empty array even if the checkboxes arechecked